strange routing table entries
My Linux network device cannot be access outside my local network.
I checked the routing table, and found the following:
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0

While it is working normally, it only contains the entry 2 and 3.  But around 1 minute after booting up, entry 1 and 4 are added, and the device is not accessible outside the subnet. After resetting the routing table, it ends up with the entry 2 and 3, which is good again, until the next bootup.
I believe the issue the entry 1 causing the issue. Do you know why entry 1 is added? My setup is inside a subnet of a large cooperate network. If I isolate my setup from the rest of the network, entry 1 and 4 would not be generated.

@Spiff, very well, I shall revise my comment: so the first and fourth routes (and the associated 169.254.x.y address) are added by AVAHI, the network auto-configuration implementation for linux (on windows its zero-conf and on apple its Bonjour). Avahi uses service and endpoint discovery protocols like DNS-SD for enumerating peer network services and mDNS (.local) for naming, which will work even on a network with that doesn't have DHCP, DNS, or Directory services.  Mabey disable avahi-daemon and see if the IP and routes go away.
